# How can I display different menu items based on the user's role in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, menu, menuitem

I'm using the [meanjs](http://meanjs.org/) stack to write a web application.  I need to display a dropdown menu to all users (logged in or not), then add more elements to the dropdown when a user is logged in.

For example, say you have a list of products.  You make a dropdown menu called "Products" that contains the element "List products".  This "List products" element appears if a user is logged in or not.  If a user is logged in, display another element in the dropdown called "Edit inventory".

The meanjs site says that the stack makes use of the ["AngularJS Menus Service"](http://meanjs.org/docs.html#menus) and lists a little bit of documentation, but I can't find any more information on the usage of this service.  The linked docs mention the optional parameters `isPublic` and `roles`, but when I try to use them, there is no effect.

The code `Menus.addMenuItem('topbar', 'Bios', 'bios', 'dropdown', '/bios(/create)?');` only shows this menu item when a user is logged in.

It has the same effect as `Menus.addMenuItem('topbar', 'Bios', 'bios', 'dropdown', '/bios(/create)?', true);`.  The optional `isPublic` parameter seems to make no difference.  What am I doing wrong?

I found [this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meanjs/PpiuR7dgxUA), which is similar but not identical and also not answered satisfactorily.

To make use of the menus service in angular, is it necessary for a user to be logged in?

Comment: Add items to your menu based on `$scope.user.role` for instance. Basically create a directive for the menu, check the role of the user in the scope and decide what elements to show when he clicks your directive.

Comment: @AmalAntony I thought about that option, but I want to use the abstracted Menus service that I linked to in my question.  It looks as though the service is built to handle things like roles out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just read the meanjs MenuService source code, this is addMenuItem:

```
 this.addMenuItem = function (menuId, menuItemTitle, menuItemURL, menuItemType, menuItemUIRoute, isPublic, roles) {
  // Validate that the menu exists
  this.validateMenuExistance(menuId);
  // Push new menu item
  this.menus[menuId].items.push({
    title: menuItemTitle,
    link: menuItemURL,
    menuItemType: menuItemType || 'item',
    menuItemClass: menuItemType,
    uiRoute: menuItemUIRoute || '/' + menuItemURL,
    isPublic: isPublic || this.menus[menuId].isPublic,
    roles: roles || this.defaultRoles,
    items: [],
    shouldRender: shouldRender
  });
  // Return the menu object
  return this.menus[menuId];
};
```

From this code, if you want to reset the `isPublic`, you should call the func with both `menuItemUIRoute` and the `isPublic`.

Cause if you don't pass the `menuItemUIRoute`. The parameters will be mixed up.

P.S This is [Source Code](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/public/dist/application.js) in line 237, and the document is not right or this is a bug. Hope this can work for you. : )

Comment: @Tylerzyang I'm still a little confused.  Did I not pass the menuItemUIRoute in the calls that I posted in the original question?

Comment: Oh, it was my mistake. I just read [this doc](http://meanjs.org/docs.html#menus) .It seems the fifth parameter is `isPublic`(should be a bool). But in your code the parameter is a `/bios(/create)?`. Maybe you should change the the parameters ?

Comment: @macsj200 Is everything ok~?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

in core menu service

**replace

// Define a set of default roles

```
 this.defaultRoles = ['user'];
```

with

```
 this.defaultRoles = ['user','admin'];**
```

And in articles config

For Main Menu

Menus.addMenuItem('topbar', 'Articles', 'articles', 'dropdown', '/articles(/create)?', true, ['admin']);

For Sub Menu

Menus.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'articles', 'New Article', 'articles/create', 'menuItemUIRoute', true, ['admin']);